# R: Alternative to using which() that returns rows / columns based on row / header names

Tags: r

I am using a data frame grid `df` such as the one below:

```
   1  2  3  4  5
1  0  0  0  0  0
2  0  0  0  0  0
3  0  4  0  0  0
4  0  0  0  2  2
```

in which I am trying to find the position of certain values. So far I have used the below code:

```
which(df==2, arr.ind=TRUE)

#  row col
#4   4   4
#4   4   5
```

but it has become apparent that this returns the position of the values with respect to the cells in the ".csv" file and ignores the headers and rows that I set to 'TRUE' when I imported the ".csv" file.

So far this has not been an issue as the row / column names have matched up. However, if I had the following row names / header:

```
   A  B  C  D  E
a  0  0  0  0  0
b  0  0  0  0  0
c  0  4  0  0  0
d  0  0  0  2  2

df <- structure(list(A = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), B = c(0L, 0L, 4L, 0L), 
C = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), D = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 2L), E = c(0L, 0L, 
0L, 2L)), .Names = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c("a", "b", "c", "d"))
```

the result would remain the same as if I used the first grid.

```
which(df==2, arr.ind=TRUE)

#  row col
#d   4   4
#d   4   5
```

Is there an alternative to instead returns the result referencing the row names / headers of the file? I expect:

```
# row col
#   d   D
#   d   E
```

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
ind <- which(df==2, arr.ind=TRUE)
data.frame(row = row.names(df)[ind[, 1]], col = names(df)[ind[, 2]])
# cbind(row = row.names(df)[ind[, 1]], col = names(df)[ind[, 2]])
```